# Why can't I setup an SSHFS share? "OSXFUSE file system is not available" error

Tags: macos, ssh, virtualbox, centos, sshfs

I'm trying to setup an SSHFS share from my local machine to a remote machine, but it is not working. I'm getting the error OSXFUSE file system is not available (see below). How to fix this??

FYI, my local machine is a MacBook Pro laptop running OSX 10.9.3. The remote machine is actually a VirtualBox on the same hardware running CentOS.

```
% brew install sshfs                                # <---- SSHFS is installed
Warning: sshfs-2.5.0 already installed

% brew install osxfuse                              # <---- OSX Fuse is installed
Warning: osxfuse-2.6.4 already installed

% ssh remote_user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX                   # <---- See, SSH works!!
Last login: Wed Jun 18 18:36:11 2014 from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
[remote_user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ~]% exit

% sudo mkdir /mnt
% sudo mkdir /mnt/Share    
% sudo sshfs -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote_user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/ /mnt/Share
the OSXFUSE file system is not available (-1)
the OSXFUSE file system is not available (1)
```

I tried solution described [**here**](https://medium.com/dev-tricks/mount-a-remote-filesystem-with-sshfs-8a37e85b39ee). But it didn't work for me:

```
% sudo kextunload -b com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs
(kernel) Kext com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs not found for unload request.
Failed to unload com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs - (libkern/kext) not found.
```

Comment: I have no MAC but have you ever installed a module you are trying to unload? If not, it's not strange that this command gives you an error. See [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130838/unable-to-mount-remote-directory-using-sshfs) how a different MAC user has solved the same problem you have.

Comment: This is a far stretch, but have you tried `modprobe osxfuse`?

Comment: I also have no Mac, but in the articles [article1](https://medium.com/dev-tricks/mount-a-remote-filesystem-with-sshfs-8a37e85b39ee) and [article2](http://serverfault.com/questions/606471/why-cant-i-setup-an-sshfs-share-osxfuse-file-system-is-not-available-error) I can see additional steps after the installation of sshfs, of cp and chmod. Maybe you should have look.

Comment: I installed osxfuse using the .pkg provided on their github page. This works, although obviously it doesn't show up in homebrew. The crucial files installed seems to be installed in the `/Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/` package, in particular the kext can also be found in there. Perhaps you'd want to check if that it's there?

Comment: Have you tried to run  `sudo /bin/cp -RfX #{opt_prefix}/Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs /Library/Filesystems` and 
`sudo chmod +s /Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/Support/load_osxfusefs` from the caveat in the osxfuse homebrew fomula?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error you did:

```
% sudo kextunload -b com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs
(kernel) Kext com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs not found for unload request.
Failed to unload com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs - (libkern/kext) not found.
```

But then I just proceeded with the rest of the instructions from that link:

```
# Use new kernel extension:
sudo /bin/cp -RfX \
/usr/local/Cellar/osxfuse/2.6.2/Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs /Library/Filesystems
sudo chmod +s \
  /Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/Support/load_osxfusefs
```

And now it's working fine. Hope that helps.